# pinescript coding for tradingview

Tags: pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4, technical-indicator

> 

I need a pinescript code for below scenario. Can anyone help please...
tEma=(close,25)

*if* current candle crossesover tEma

*then* calculate close price minus tEma price(value)`close-tEMA`

if the value is <5, bgcolor it should be green with 80% transparency. Else NA.

likewise

*if* current candle crossesbelow tEma

*then* calculate difference between tEma-close

if the value is <5, bgcolor should be red with 80% transparency. Else NA.

will be grateful for the help

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your script in code and what exactly your trying to do?